# Displaying "COUNT" from a point-shapefile in ArcGIS 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I've tried a number of ways, labeling, unique values, etc.  I know I'm right there but can't get it, it will just display features by the "NAME" field.  Also if I try to use symbolize by quantities, only fields I get are numerical I'm guessing, but cannot be aggregated to a total there.  I cannot find the Field Calculator either, which I thought I could maybe add a field and have a "SUM" field added and then label it that way.

End Goal:

I have point features in various states, and the application needs to display the number of those features within each state.

Comment: If one of these answers worked for you please mark it as correct instead of thanking us as an answer. Glad to help. Take a look here if you'd like too learn how to properly use the GIS SE. https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done by using a spatial join. Here are some step by step instructions:

http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000008599

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use the [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) geoprocessing tool.

After running the tool, a new field `Join_Count` will be calculated in the states feature class with the number of features that fell within each state.

Target features: states; join features: points.